# Каким образом можно вернуть данные из Laravel во Vue

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, vue.js

Подскажите, будьте так добры! Есть проблема в SPA приложении, написанном в связке Laravel+Vue.

При переходе по страницам  приложения с помощью мыши все работает прекрасно, все данные из БД подгружаются, и в целом все выглядит так, как надо. Данные подгружаются даже на каждой отдельной странице каждого поста.
Но в момент, когда я нахожусь на странице какого-либо поста, например, http:// localhost/post/7, и нажму F5, чтобы перезагрузить страницу, все, что я увижу, будет вот это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И, собственно, я даже понимаю почему это происходит - при обновлении страницы мне возвращается один лишь json-объект, а не страница с данными, как я хотел бы. После обновления все стили, все элементы, все скрипты со страницы пропадают и остается один только json-объект.

Отсюда вопрос - как мне вернуть страницу с необходимыми данными, а не только сами данные и не только одну страницу без данных из Laravel?

**welcome.blade.php**

```
...
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
...
```

Так я получаю данные из БД:

**singlePost.vue**

```
created(){
        this.$http.get('/post/' + this.id).then((response) => {
            this.post = response.body;
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }
```

И роутер:

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/post/{id}', function ($id) {

    return \App\Post::find($id);

});
```

Comment: в консоли какие ошибки после обновления появляются?

Comment: Ошибок нет, только предупреждение:
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json: "http://v.dev/post/8".

Comment: Нет это проблема скорее всего кэша, попробуй в заголовке добавить no-cache $response->header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, must-revalidate');

Comment: Друзья! Всех неравнодушных благодарю за помощь! С проблемой разобрался таки...